# Cleaning up this code [FILE INPUT]

Tags: c++, oop, file-io

I have to read from a file that has lines like this:

```
255 0 0 15 x l Red Yellow,Gray,Blue,Green
```

Let's say I want to read the first 5 elements of this line (space delimited). I'm currently doing it like this:

```
std::string line;
while(file.good()) {
    getline(worldfile, line);
    unsigned space = line.find(" ");
    unsigned r = atoi(line.substr(0, space).c_str());
    line = line.substr(space + 1);
    space = line.find(" ");
    unsigned g = atoi(line.substr(0, space).c_str());
    line = line.substr(space + 1);
    space = line.find(" ");
    unsigned b = atoi(line.substr(0, space).c_str());
    line = line.substr(space + 1);
    space = line.find(" ");
    unsigned gold = atoi(line.substr(0, space).c_str());
    line = line.substr(space + 1);
    space = line.find(" ");
    char resource = line.substr(0, space).c_str()[0];
    // do something with these values
}
```

I don't like the looks of this code. While it works perfectly fine for my files, I don't like that it's just line after line of code. This makes it really hard to read.
I'm also planning on releasing my code (it's for a game) as open source when it's done, but I'm ashamed of releasing code like this.

How can I clean this up?

Comment: For starters. learn about extraction operators for streams  (i.e. `std::istream& operator >>()(std::stream&, int&)` to name one you would use here). A `std::istringstream` would probably also come in handy for individual line-processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work to read them all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   fstream file;
    file.open("file.txt",ios::in);
    unsigned r,g,b,gold;
    char i,f;
    string line;
    while(file >> r >> g >> b >> gold >> i >> f)
    {
        getline(file,line);
        cout << r << " " << g << " "<< b << " "<< gold << " "<< i << " "<< f << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would that take care of the spaces? Or would I have to do this? `file >> " " >> g >> " " >> b >> " " >> i >> " " >> gold;`?

Comment: It takes care of spaces, test it :)

Comment: I did what you suggested and reading this line `255 0 0 15 x` generates this output:  25500. I used this code: `unsigned gold;
   char resource;
   worldfile >> color->r >> color->g >> color->b >> gold >> resource;
   std::cout << color->r << color->g << color->b << gold << resource << std::endl;
   getline(worldfile, line);`

Comment: Also, if you're no doing anything with `line`, then `ignore` might be better than `getline`.  (But `getline` is fine too)